# Does this implication hold given this function?

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, inverse

Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} (f(x) - 2x) = 0$ imply that $\lim_{y \to \infty} (g(y) - \frac{y}{2}) = 0$?

**My original function is**

> $f(x) = \sqrt{4x^2 + 1}$ for $x \in [0, \infty)$

**with the inverse I found**

> $g(y) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2 - 1}}{2}$

Comment: You probably need to say that g is an inverse of f.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon >0$. Then there exists $T$ such that $x>T$ implies $|f(x)-2x| <\epsilon$. If $y >f(T)$ we can take  $x=g(y)$ to get $|y-2g(y)|<\epsilon$ or $|g(y)-\frac y 2|<\epsilon/2<\epsilon$. If you call $f(T)$ as $S$ it follows that $|g(y)-\frac y 2|<\epsilon$ whenever $y >S$.